# Will application with more or fewer modules load faster in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In term of loading time in Angular 4, the application with more modules or the application have fewer modules will load faster? And why?

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, well.. what do you think? What will load faster? Something that's 150KB (almost no modules) or something that's 2400KB (lots of modules).

Which is the same as asking, which file loads faster, the smaller one, or the bigger one...

Well obviously the smaller one will load faster. As well the parsing of the response will be faster, interpreting the JavaScript will be faster.

If however your core module stays the same size, and you have a lot of lazy loaded modules which are triggered by routes, the speed doesn't significantly change, because only that module which belongs to that specific lazy route will be loaded

Comment: Ok maybe I need to clear up my question a bit, I mean If I have 1 app with many features then in senario1 I have 1 module for each feature, senario 2 I have only 1 module for whole appication. Which one will load faster?

Comment: @QuangNhanNguyen If they all use the same code, but one is compartmentalized in feature modules then they will still load in the same amount of time, because feature modules are not lazy loaded, and will be included in the wrapped bundle